# Sublime text 3 - Unable to load plugin clean-css please make sure that it is installed under or at the same level as less

Tags: less, sublimetext3, clean-css

The message always show up when I save my less file.
I already installed plugin - [Less](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LESS) and [Less2Css](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Less2Css), and also npm install less-plugin-clean-css, but it's still not working.
How should I do now?....

[image: Sample region image]

Answer (score 0):

I just update Xcode app on my macOS Mojave (10.14) and install sublime text3 again.
It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue pertaining to LESS' CSS minification modules. As a workaround, you can disable minification.  To do this, open Sublime Text 3 and navigate to `Preferences` > `Browse Packages` > `Less2css` -> `Settings - User`. Use the following user configuration instead:

```
{
    "minify": false
}
```